# elasticsearch bulk script does not work neither with elasticsearch.yml change

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

When I try to run a curl command like:

```
curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary "@bulk_prova.elastic"; echo
```

Where bulk_prova.elastic is:

```
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "type1", "_index" : "indexName"} }{ "script" : "ctx._source.topic = \"topicValue\""}
```

I got this error

```
{"took":19872,"errors":true,"items":[{"update":{"_index":"indexName","_type":"type1","_id":"1","status":400,"error":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"failed to execute script","caused_by":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"scripts of type [inline], operation [update] and lang [groovy] are disabled"}}}}]}
```

I searched to solve the issue and I've managed the elasticsearch.yml file to enable the dynamic script, but every time that I try to change the file  and stop elastic when I restart the elasticsearch service it does not start.

Due to this strange behavior I do not know how to do to solve the issue.

I have the 2.2.0 version and my intention is to add a field to a index (for now) or more than an index (once the problem is solved)

Comment: What did you add to the `elasticsearch.yml` file?

Comment: script.disable_dynamic: false

Answer (score 1):

In Elasticsearch 2.3 it has been modified from:

script.disable_dynamic: false

TO:

script.file: true
script.indexed: true